# Vimeo API - Unable to initiate an upload

Tags: php, vimeo

I've a problem when i try to upload video to viemo

here's my code

```
$file_name = "video.mp4";

$file_name = realpath($file_name);

$uri = $client->upload($file_name, array(
    "name" => "New Video",
    "description" => "10 seconds video for testing"
));

echo "Your video URI is: " + $uri;
```

and I get this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException: Unable to initiate an upload.`

can you help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Has your app been approved for upload access, or have you not yet requested that capability? Does your auth token have upload and edit scope? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos